# How to post data in JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

```
"type_of_advertisement":["ATM","Banner/Poster","Stalls"]
```

html code is

```
    input(type='checkbox', value='Mobile/Communication Tower', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
                | Mobile/Communication Tower
              label.checkbox-inline
                input(type='checkbox', value='Banner/Poster', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
                | Banner/Poster
              label.checkbox-inline
                input(type='checkbox', value='Hoarding Board', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
                | Hoarding Board
              label.checkbox-inline
                input(type='checkbox', value='Stalls', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
                | Stalls
              label.checkbox-inline
                input(type='checkbox', value='Digital Offline Marketing', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
                | Digital Offline Marketing
              label.checkbox-inline
                input(type='checkbox', value='Area for Product Display', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
                | Area for Product Display
```

angular code is

```
type_of_advertisement:[$scope.type_of_advertisement]
```

The problem occurs is when i hit a one check box all check  boxes automatic select.
and get the api response like

```
"type_of_advertisement":["true"]
```

So what can i code so i get the desired api result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it by having an array like this:

```
$scope.rows = [{
    value: "Mobile/Communication Tower"
  }, {
    value: "Banner/Poster"
  }, {
    value: "Hoarding Board"
  }, {
    value: "Stalls"
  }];
```

And HTML (inside `ng-repeat`):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.selected" />{{row.value}}</label>
```

Now, before calling API, you can reform your array, something like this:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.selectedRows = $scope.rows.reduce(function(arr, val) {
        if(val.selected) arr.push(val.value)
      return arr
    }, []);
  };
```

to get `$scope.selectedRows` becomean array like this:

```
[
  "Banner/Poster",
  "Hoarding Board"
]
```

[**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4aog7m3/1/)

Comment: @aviralgarg glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Working Plunker - https://embed.plnkr.co/mJijSg/

All the elements are binded to the same `ng-model`. When you change its value, all the checkboxes will change. Use differents `ng-models`.

In this example, I wrote several checkboxes with the same `ng-model` and differents `ng-models`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of requiring `ngmodel` in a directive:

```
input(type='checkbox', data-toa="" value='Mobile/Communication Tower', ng-model='type_of_advertisement')
// at all the inputs put a directive called "toa" 

app.directive('toa', function() { //<---bind a directive here
   return {
     restrict: 'A', 
     require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       if (!ngModel) return; 

       element.on('change', function() {
         if(element.checked){
            scope.type_of_advertisement.push(element.value);
         }
       });
    }
});
```